# How to make jedi:goto-definition open definition in split buffer

Tags: emacs

jedi:goto-definition works wonderfully, but it opens the definition in the same buffer that I'm editing in. For just looking up references it would me much better if it opened the definition of a function in a split pane and kept the cursor where it is.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could advise `jedi:goto-definition` so Emacs splits the frame before running `jedi:goto-definition`, and goes back to your buffer afterwards.

```
(defadvice jedi:goto-definition (around definition-in-other-window activate)
  "Goto definition in a different window."
  (interactive)
  ;; remove any current frame splits
  (delete-other-windows)
  ;; split the frame vertically
  (split-window-right)
  ;; switch focus to the window on the right
  (other-window 1)
  ad-do-it
  ;; switch back to the window on the left
  (other-window 1))
```